# Get user input from IDE/Console in selenium webderiver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-input

I want to get the key(send key) from user input how should I implement it?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vehicleNum']")).sendKeys("1121");
```

in input box what ever user type i want gen then i want to send through selenium?

Comment: Do you want to get the value "1121" which you send using sendkeys()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even your question is not clear properly but as I am assuming you need below solution.
To get the input value from textbox, you can use below code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vehicleNum']")).sendKeys("1121");
 String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vehicleNum']")).getAttribute("value");
 System.out.println(str);
```

> Program output will be "1121"

Answer (score 3):

You can use builtin Scanner class to get the input from system console. Below code might give you some idea.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = sc.nextLine();
//now pass name in sendkeys.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vehicleNum']")).sendKeys(name);
```

Else if you need to get the text from one of the webelement, identify the webelement and use getText() to get the string value.

```
String value = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='vehicleNum']")).sendKeys(value);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks..

Comment: i want to get from website

Answer (score 3):

As a demo I am providing you a sample block of code with respect to the URL `https://accounts.google.com` which will ask the Input from User to provide `Email or Phone` and then click on `Next` button:

> Using `Scanner` you will get the user prompt on the IDE console as **`Enter your Email or Phone :`**. Do remember to close the scanner explicitly through `scanner_user.close();` to prevent **`Resource Leakage`**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class GMAIL_LOGIN_SCANNER 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        Scanner scanner_user, scanner_pass;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
        WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scanner_user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Email or Phone : ");
        String user = scanner_user.nextLine();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys(user);
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
        scanner_user.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nodejs [Readline](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) for waiting user input as my [github example](https://github.com/lcd11001/selenium-webdriver/releases/tag/v0.0.1)