# How to ask selenium web driver to wait until user input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i have a registration page in which there is a OTP field. How to ask selenium to wait until otp get entered into that field before click on registration button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get user input from IDE/Console in selenium webderiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140603/get-user-input-from-ide-console-in-selenium-webderiver)

Comment: Can you share with us the relavant part of the HTML, The HTML of the OTP fiels and some of its's parent tags?