# Selenium: How to identify an iron icon?

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I do not find an elegant solution to address with Selenium an iron-icon.

```
<iron-icon style="..." icon="vaadin:sign-out" title="logout"></iron-icon>
```

I made it with Xpath and it works but I would like to have a more elegant solution because Xpath is such thing.

Does anyone know a trick?

Comment: With css I'd go with: `[icon="vaadin:sign-out"]`

Answer (score 0):

The `<iron-icon>` element is from the [***svg***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41829000/7429447) namespace.

To click on the *`<iron-icon>`* element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) / [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *Java* and *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("iron-icon[icon='vaadin:sign-out']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='iron-icon' and @title='logout']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : For *Python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on interacting with SVG elements in:

- [Reading title tag in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544849/7429447)
- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024531/7429447)

Comment: Thank you for helping. WebDriverWait ist not furthermore supported that way. Ich changed ist to: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));` and then the line with `WebElement logout_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg iron-icon[title='logout']"));` It does not work, throws this info: "Unable to locate element: svg iron-icon[title='logout']" and in addition the editor says to that line with findElement "The value of the local variable logout_button is not used".

Comment: @pixelhead Do you realize that you are yet to mention which Language binding art you are using, e.g. Java/Python. Btw, did you find some time to go through the embedded links and discussions?

Comment: 1/x
Sorry, I am pretty new to this ... I thought I added all information needed. I did my research but probably I simply do not understand or do not find it. 

Language bindings: Java 
Stable: 4.1.2 (January 30, 2022)
https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: 2/x
WebDriverWait:
"The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, long) is deprecated"
"Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."
/ Compiled from WebDriverWait.java (version 1.8 : 52.0, super bit)
// Signature: Lorg/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait<Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;>;
public class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait extends org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait

Comment: 3/x
No idea why this shows up because my imports seem correctly:
`import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

Comment: 4/4
it is especially about these two, right? They are in my imports.
`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

Comment: Check the relevant imports from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144131/7429447) discussion.

Comment: Everything is ok now, it works. 
Solution:
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
WebElement logout_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iron-icon[icon='vaadin:sign-out']"));
logout_button.click();`

Comment: So you have to say `By.cssSelector("svg iron-icon[title='logout']")` still doesn't works?

Comment: In my case it did not work. I also tried without svg and just iron-icon.

Comment: @pixelhead Okay, updated my answer as per the working solution.