# How to continue automation after entering OTP manually using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-input

Using selenium webdriver I am testing login page and some more tabs using eclipse, maven, testng, but in Login page there is OTP verification. So I put OTP manually so. How to continue next proces as a automation?

Answer (score 3):

To continue automation after entering OTP manually using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) would be to use the [Scanner](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp) class as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_mobile_field")).sendKeys("9818414799");
scanner_user = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the OTP: ");
String user = scanner_user.nextLine();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_otp_field")).sendKeys(user);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Get user input from IDE/Console in selenium webderiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144131/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enter that manually, you can use someone's otp generator library, like pyotp in python.

```
import pyotp
totp = pyotp.TOTP('HASHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
ida2f = totp.now()
```

for java do you have
https://github.com/BastiaanJansen/otp-java

To resolve the OTP, you generally need to select the "iframe" first, for example in python.

```
                            try:
                                iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="xxxxxOTP"]')
                                driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

                                iKeys = 0
                                for strs in ida2f:
                                    iKeys = iKeys + 1
                                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="xxxx-html"]/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/input[{iKeys}]').click()
                                    time.sleep(0.1)
                                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="xxxx-html"]/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/input[{iKeys}]').send_keys(strs)
                                    time.sleep(0.1)

                                driver.switch_to.default_content()
                                time.sleep(3)
                            except:
                                continue
```

To be reliable, I like to send key by key, and remember about the **iframe**, it is very important.

For example (java):

```
driver.switchTo().frame("xxxxxxx");
```

And remember go to default frame after:

```
switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: What OP wants is to solve the OTP, and what you suggested there is a library for OTP system.

Comment: To solve the OTP it is not as simple as looking for the OTP and it is ready, you must select the iframe before.